# No calendar offset when using custom data bundle for minute data in zipline

Tags: python, zipline

I wrote my own zipline bundle to ingest cryptocurrency prices from my exchange. The ingestion runs smoothly and I checked the database and saw my minute data in it.

I tried to run a really simple algorithm to verify my bundle, but I ran into an exception.

My algorithm looks like this:

```
def initialize(context):
    # I tried to run it without this line as well
    context.sim_params._emission_rate = 'minute' 


def handle_data(context, data):    
    order(symbol('ETHBTC'), 10)
    record(ETHBTC=data.current(symbol('ETHBTC'), 'price'))
```

The last line gives me the following exception:

```
File "python3.5/site-packages/zipline/data/us_equity_pricing.py", line 710, in sid_day_index
offset = day_loc - self._calendar_offsets[sid]
KeyError: Equity(0 [ETHBTC])
```

I looked into this further and found that zipline uses the daily bar reader to get a calendar offset for the symbol "ETHBTC". But my daily bar data is empty since I am just ingesting minutely data.

According to the zipline documentation, ingesting daily bar data is not mandatory from which I concluded that zipline will resample the minute data to daily data if needed.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there something I have to do start the resampling of minute to daily bar data?

Cheers!